# Android activity wont load items at first

Tags: android

In my application I have empty activity and plus button which opens new activity in which I type some title and few text fields and then save. When i save that item is added to the 1. activity but not shown. I need to go to some other activity and when i come back its then loaded. Same goes for 2nd item after its added but after there are 2 or more items it always loads all the items, im not using aSyncTask, i just load data from database. Anyone knows what could be the problem?
Is there any itemView.function() that reloads all the items in a activity?

Comment: If your problem is something like data is not updated after add new data while still in that activity you can say adapater to notify for the data added. Use `notifyDataSetChanged();` to your adapter after pushing the data. This will inform the adapter and display the newly added data.

Comment: So i need to add ``` adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();``` to the activity where it loads the items?

Comment: Yes! This will inform the adapter to load the new data..!!

Comment: Im using findViewById on 7 itmes, and i think it takes too much time to load so it doenst load at all, but that is only problem when there are 2 or less item. I implemented adapter globally so i can use >adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  in function sbut still no luck, any other suggestions?

Comment: doesn't seem like this has anything to do with android studio, rather just android, so i've removed the tag and the reference to it

Comment: With that code and description in your question. I believe that's the only suggestion I can provide, edit your question with a clear explaining description and code to understand your issue

Comment: please post all of your code in your activity

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: post your activity code as well not adapter

Comment: lets say i have parent activity which shows 3 types of card, after i click first one, it shows all the cards of that type and it should load those type of cards but its not loading if there are 2 or less sometimes, and there is button in corner that when clicked on leads to another activity where you can add new card, and when i click save it takes me back to the activity where are all the cards of that type, and then it should load new card that was just added but as i said it does not show it until i exti to the parent activity and come back

Comment: @sashabeliy added more code check it out

Comment: @ForthRider can you share your whole as github file I will check it

Comment: @ForthRider put break point in adapter and button run in debug mode step by step there are should some problem

Comment: Not possible sorry, il just leave it like how it is for now, i dont know why is it not loading, maybe findViewById is kinda heavy function

Comment: @sashabeliy i did run it now in debugger,and on CardDisplayAdapter after card_iban = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iban_number);   it should show the card but its not showing anything, any way of refreshing the elemnt or activity

Comment: @sashabeliy solved it, recycler view height was set to warp_content instead of match_parent

Comment: @ForthRider it is great that you have solved issue happy for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that my xml file that containted RecyclerView was set to wrap contnent so i changed

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/card_item">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

to

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LiveData for that and observe it to your Main Activity.
I assume that you are using ROOM library for your database and MVVM architecture. Here's the example from my project.

```
             public LiveData<List<Todo>> getAllTodo() {
             return allTodo;
             } //This is from my ViewModel class.
```

and I observe it from my main activity

```
      viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class);
      viewModel.getAllTodo().observe(this, new Observer<List<Todo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Todo> todos) {
            todoAdapter.setTodos(todos);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have exact same code, its not problem in that, im using same thing on my other activites and there that is working but here when im using findViewById its not showing always, just sometimes